# Unpermitted operand to operator '>>' and '&' (MISRA C)

Tags: c, embedded, misra

When checking some code with Misra, it has generated following messages

```
Unpermitted operand to operator '>>' [MISRA 2012 Rule 10.1 required]
Unpermitted operand to operator '&' [MISRA 2012 Rule 10.1 required]
```

I wasn't able to understand the issue, and the description of Rule 10.1 is very general and does not help a lot. The relevant piece of code is bellow.

```
float  variable2;
variable2= 814.00f;
Data[0] = (((Int16) variable2) >> 8) & ((Int16)0xFF);
Data[1] =  ((Int16) variable2) & ((Int16)0xFF);
```

What is the issue with the use of operators in this code?

Comment: Maybe because `Int16` is a signed type?

Comment: I wondered that but it's also for the `&`. Perhaps MISRA doesn't like the loss in significance even though a cast would normally conceal it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use signed integers in bitwise arithmetic, ever. There is a lot of poorly-defined behavior associated with it. Left-shifting a negative value gives undefined behavior. Right-shifting a negative value gives implementation-defined behavior (either arithmetic or logical shift).

Therefore MISRA-C has a requirement that all such variables should be of what they call *essentially unsigned* type.

In addition, using a 16 bit type no matter signedness isn't safe on a 32-bit system, because they will be implicitly promoted to 32-bit signed `int`. I will assume that you are using a 32-bit system, or otherwise the use of floating point numbers likely makes little sense in the first place.

In your case, you can't go directly from float to unsigned, as you would lose the sign bit. Meaning you have to go one step to signed type first.

```
float    f32 = 814.00f;
int32_t  s32 = (int32_t)f32;
uint32_t u32 = (uint32_t)s32;

Data[0] = ((u32 >> 8) & 0xFFu);
Data[1] = (u32 & 0xFFu);
```

This should be MISRA-C compliant, though it depends on the type of `Data` too.

- `u` suffix on integer constants is sufficient, you don't need to cast them.
- Use stdint.h types and not some home-made types.
- The extra parenthesis around the operands of `&` is required for advisory MISRA-C:2012 12.1. Your code was not compliant with this rule, the above code is.

Answer (score 0):

> ... the description of Rule 10.1 is very general and does not help a lot.

Do you have a copy of MISRA C:2012 (or later)?

If you did, you could look the table, find the row for `>>` and the column for *Signed* - which has a number 6 in it. Ditto for `&`.

This states that shift and bit-wise operations should only be performed on operands of essentially unsigned type.

```
float  variable2;
variable2= 814.00f;
Data[0] = (((Int16) variable2) >> 8) & ((Int16)0xFF);  // The problem is here
Data[1] =  ((Int16) variable2)       & ((Int16)0xFF);  // ... and here
```

You are shifting a `signed integer` (cast from `float`, which is a separate issue) and then doing a bit-wise and on that... your tool is correct.